# No Windows CE in the OpenNETCF dll file

Tags: c#, .net, compact-framework, opennetcf

I'm developing a Windows CE app using .NET Compact Framework 2.0 and C#. I wanted to add OpenNetCF and found the repository on GitHub. However, the OpenNETCF does not have an OpenNETCF.WindowsCE namespace. Does anybody knows why it is not there?
I'm aware that I can download the OpenNETCF.WindowsCE.dll separately and solve it, but I was just curious to know why it isn't added to the original OpenNETCF.dll in the first place? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is OpenNetCF and SmartDeviceFramework. OpenNetCF.WindowsCE is part of SDF: https://www.pcreview.co.uk/threads/where-to-get-dll-for-opennetcf-windowsce-devicemanagement-class.3169051/

The SDF (Community Edition of OpenNetCF) is available at https://github.com/ctacke/sdf/tree/master/OpenNETCF.WindowsCE/OpenNETCF.WindowsCE

I am not sure what happens to OpenNetCF, as the old web sites are not available any more.

Comment: Thank you. It's just that I expected the library to be one dll file, e.g. SDF.dll. But I guess it's not. Or maybe I'm not looking in the right subdirs.I also found the archive on codeplex at https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=opennetcf, but there I noticed all the separate dll files as well. Do you know why it is so divided?

Comment: The separate function areas are divded. That ist right. And the SDF ist available as free source.

Comment: As the function areas are divided, you only need to include what you need and do not break the DLL resource limit on Windows CE/Mobile.